# os.getcwd() returns a URL (weird)

Tags: python, jenkins

I have some debugging code:

```
_LOGGER.debug("Output path: [%s]", os.getcwd())
```

This is running inside a job in Jenkins.

In the output, I'm seeing:

```
2015-06-12 15:37:26,548 - packager.packager_main_2 - DEBUG - Output path: [<http://jenkins.url/job/adam2-trunk-dev/ws/]>
```

This is not a message that I usually pay attention to, but, it, at some point, must've returned a valid path or I wouldn't have found it useful whenever it was that I had added it.

Does anyone know how/why os.getcwd() would return a URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with os.getcwd(), it's just Jenkins replacing the path with the job URL in console output (either in e-mail or web), to see the real value here, choose "View as plain text" under Console Output.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?